# Cannot create new kafka topic in confluent cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I'm trying to create a new kafka topic in confluent cloud, but it gives me an 'authorization failed' error.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I tried creating my free cluster on different cloud providers but it always give me the same error : "Authorization failed" whatever the name of the topic or the number of partitions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not Confluent Support.

Comment: I have the same problem as you and @DavidDaSilva.

Comment: @OneCricketeer It is not about being a Confluent Support. It is about helping to solve a problem. It should be the purpose of people on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Plicatibu There is nothing that can be solved here. Either [the hosted service is down](https://status.confluent.cloud/), or the authentication credentials are incorrect. Only Confluent will be able to resolve either case.

Answer (score 0):

give yourself a role `CloudClusterAdmin` from confluent cloud UI `Accounts & access`, then you should able to manage cluster.